# Boost preprocessor - strange result

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, boost-preprocessor

Check the following macro:

```
#define INPUT (char, "microsecond", "us")(int, "millisecond", "ms")(int, "second", "s")(int, "minute", "min")(float, "hour", "h")
```

Goal is to add double parentheses around each tuple resulting in:

```
((char, "microsecond", "us"))((int, "millisecond", "ms"))((int, "second", "s"))((int, "minute", "min"))((float, "hour", "h"))
```

Now I use the following macros to do this job:

```
#define ADD_PAREN_1(A, B, C) ((A, B, C)) ADD_PAREN_2
#define ADD_PAREN_2(A, B, D) ((A, B, C)) ADD_PAREN_1
#define ADD_PAREN_1_END
#define ADD_PAREN_2_END
#define OUTPUT0 ADD_PAREN_1 INPUT
#define OUTPUT1 BOOST_PP_CAT( OUTPUT0, _END )
```

The result is as follows:

OUTPUT0 is fine:

```
((char, "microsecond", "us")) ((int, "millisecond", C)) ((int, "second", "s")) ((int, "minute", C)) ((float, "hour", "h")) ADD_PAREN_2
```

But when BOOST_PP_CAT is called the result of OUTPUT1 is:

```
float
```

I do not understand this behaviour. Any hints ?

Note I use Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Hint of the day: Don't use macros.

Comment: why not just use search-and-replace in region?  Is there some reason the parens need to be doubled by the preprocessor instead of the editor?

Comment: @AShelly: Yes there is a reason. I did describe it already but the user did delete his answer. The reason is that the result is forwarded to the BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH macro which does require the extra parentheses. Therefore manual search and replace is no option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocessor works by scanning and expanding. So when it expands your `OUTPUT0` macro, it gives:

```
ADD_PAREN_1 INPUT
^
```

Then it scans the next token to see if it is a parenthesis, and if it is it will invoke `ADD_PAREN_1` as a function macro. However, it will only see INPUT, So it doesn't invoke `ADD_PAREN_1`. Next it scans and expands the next token:

```
ADD_PAREN_1 INPUT
            ^
```

Which will result in this:

```
ADD_PAREN_1 (char, "microsecond", "us")(int, "millisecond", "ms")(int, "second", "s")(int, "minute", "min")(float, "hour", "h")
            ^
```

Next when you try to use `OUTPUT1`, it will expand to this:

```
BOOST_PP_CAT( OUTPUT0, _END )
```

Which `BOOST_PP_CAT` will expand `OUTPUT0` and then concat the tokens, so you will ultimately get this:

```
 ADD_PAREN_1 (char, "microsecond", "us")(int, "millisecond", "ms")(int, "second", "s")(int, "minute", "min")(float, "hour", "h") ## _END
```

As you can see you are concating a parenthesis with `_END`, which is not allowed, and results in a compiler error. In Visual Studio, you may see different results, as their preprocessor works in mysterious ways.

Ultimately, to make it work you just need to apply an extra scan in the `OUTPUT0` macro, something like this:

```
#define X(x) x
#define OUTPUT0 X(ADD_PAREN_1 INPUT)
```

Which will work in C preprocessors, I don't know if it will exactly work in Visual Studio(I don't have access to it right now to check), but I do know this works:

```
#define ADD_PAREN(x) BOOST_PP_CAT(ADD_PAREN_1 x, _END)
#define ADD_PAREN_1(A, B, C) ((A, B, C)) ADD_PAREN_2
#define ADD_PAREN_2(A, B, D) ((A, B, C)) ADD_PAREN_1
#define ADD_PAREN_1_END
#define ADD_PAREN_2_END
#define OUTPUT1 ADD_PAREN(INPUT)
```

Which is similar to how they do it in boost. See how the [BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ASSOC_STRUCT_FILLER](https://github.com/boost-lib/fusion/blob/master/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_assoc_struct.hpp#L37) macro is used [here](https://github.com/boost-lib/fusion/blob/master/include/boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_assoc_struct.hpp#L73).

Comment: "In Visual Studio, you may see different results, as their preprocessor works in mysterious ways." Yup! Just did some heavy preprocessor work a bit ago involving many concatenations and re-expanding of newly formed macros invocations, and found many fun facts about its preprocessor... :) (For example, it treats `__VA_ARGS__` as a single token unless you expand it.) I usually call your `X` macro `EXPAND_ARG`. +1

Comment: @Paul: Thanks a lot four your answer. The trick with the extra scan did solve the problem.